# Can I use link_to to link an image and a text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, erb, font-awesome

Well, I am using "font-awesome-rails" gem. I am pretty much used to font-awesome outside Rails, but I guess it's not that popular among Rails community.

Once installed, it creates icons using the format

```
<i class="nameoftheicon"> </i>
```

I thought of using it for my site logo, which would consist of the icon from font-awesome and some text. So I tried:

```
<%= link_to "", root_path, class: "icon-puzzle-piece icon-2x" %>
<%=  link_to "My site", root_path, id: 'logo'  %>
```

It works, but when I hover, they act as two different elements.

1. What is the Rails way of combining an image and a text under a single `<a>` tag.
2. And is there any popular Rails alternative to font-awesome?

Answer (score 24):

Pass a block to `link_to` and the block will be linked

```
<%= link_to path, id: "logo" do %>
  <i class="icon-puzzle-piece icon-2x"></i>
  My Super Site
<% end %>
```

Comment: @TradeRaider great! please mark as the correct answer (click the green arrow)

Comment: @JesseWolgamott: accidentally downvoted your answer, I wanted to upvote it. If you edit it I can revote.

Answer (score 6):

Try it,

You can directly mention rails image_tag in link_to as,

```
<%= link_to image_tag("image_name")+"your text", root_path, :class=>"icon-puzzle-piece icon-2x" %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. For complex anchor such as images, just remove the first argument(the link text or anchor), and attach a block after the method.

```
link_to(root_path){<i class="icon"></i>}
```

The content inside block will become the anchor.

Comment: Hi @BillyChan, are you sure that this is supported by Rails 3.2. I am getting weird "SyntaxError in Pages#home".

Comment: @TradeRaider, of course it works and I use this often. Here is the source code of link_to, you can see how it work with blocks. If block, it will used as link text. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/380800e4a272db98f3dd267f82e0ce1e4d03f4b8/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb#L231

Comment: For some weird reason, it works with the do..end block, but not with the curly brackets (Maybe it's just me, I don't know).

Comment: @TradeRaider，that's weird. Anyway it's nice you made it working.

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys this is a good way of link w/ image (it has lot of props in case you want to css attribute for example replace "alt" or "title" etc)

```
<%= link_to image_tag("#{request.ssl? ? @image_domain_secure : @image_domain}/images/linkImage.png", {:alt=>"Alt title", :title=>"Link title"}) , "http://www.site.com"%>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are using a vector font as image but you can use image_tag too, for example:

```
<%= link_to user_root_path, :class=> "user" do
      image_tag("image.jpg", :alt => current_user.name) +
      t("dashboard.my_account")
    end %>
```

Don't forget link together both of them with "+"