# making an image a link with link_to image_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, hyperlink

I want to turn an image into a link using RoR and have tried this:

```
<%= link_to (image_tag("TLC_logo.jpg", :class => "float-right"), office_toothbrushmailbox_path) %>
```

but that doesn't seem to be working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Alot of questions on stackoverflow like this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16947094/can-i-use-link-to-to-link-an-image-and-a-text, please search first.

Comment: Get rid of the space after link_to It is unncessary and is causing problem. Apart from that everything looks good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the space after `link_to` It is unnecessary and is causing problem. Apart from that everything looks good.