# How to position border directly over active link with active_link_to? Rails 4

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, bootstrap-4

I'm currently using active_link_to to track changes in the state of my nav-bar links. When I add styling to the active state, it looks like the picture below. I would like to push the active state border to the top of the link. Twitter's nav bar is a good example of the style that I've been trying to implement. Lastly, it seems as if all states are currently active for the nav-bar when one link should only show the border active-state.

[Awesome Font Icon Nav-Item with top-border floating to the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kY5FG.png)

HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-full navbar-fixed-top bg-inverse" style="font-size: 18px;">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><%= image_tag 'logo.png' %></a>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-properties">
    <% if user_signed_in? %>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <%= active_link_to awesome_link 'fa fa-home fa-3x', home_path, :class => 'nav-item nav-link', title: 'Home', style: 'color: white' %>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <%= active_link_to awesome_link 'fa fa-commenting-o fa-3x', news_user_path(current_user), :class => 'nav-item nav-link', title: 'News', style: 'color: white' %>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <%= active_link_to awesome_link 'fa fa-globe fa-3x', discovery_index_path, :class => 'nav-item nav-link', title: 'Discovery', style: 'color: white' %>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <%= active_link_to awesome_link 'fa fa-list-alt fa-3x', notifications_user_path(current_user), :class => 'nav-item nav-link', title: 'Notifications', style: 'color: white' %>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <%= active_link_to awesome_link 'fa fa-envelope-o fa-3x', conversations_path, style: 'color: white;', title: 'Mailbox', :class => 'nav-item nav-link' %>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <%= active_link_to awesome_link 'fa fa-newspaper-o fa-3x', assignments_path, style: 'color: white;', title: 'Assignments', :active => [['assignments'], []], :class => 'nav-item nav-link' %>
        </li>
        <li class="pull-right account-button-push">
          <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <a type="button" class="btn btn-secondary-outline dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="margin-left: 12px;"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>
              Account</a>

            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
              <a><%= link_to 'Edit Account', edit_user_registration_path(current_user), style: 'text-decoration: none; text-align: center;', class: 'dropdown-item' %></a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider">
              </div>
              <a><%= link_to 'Profile Settings', user_setting_path(current_user), :class => 'dropdown-item', style: 'text-align: center' %> </a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a><%= link_to 'Subscription', new_subscription_path(current_user), :class => 'dropdown-item', style: 'text-align: center' %></a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a><%= active_link_to 'Sign out', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete, :class => 'dropdown-item', strong: true, style: 'text-align: center' %></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="pull-right">
          <%= active_link_to new_post_path, :class => 'btn btn-success', style: 'line-height: -4px;', remote: true, data: { :toggle => 'modal', :target => '#myModal'} do %>
              <div style="margin-top:4px;"><i class="fa fa-crosshairs"></i> New Experience</div>
          <% end %>
        </li>
        <li class="pull-right round-image-50-placement-fix">
          <%= link_to(image_tag(current_user.avatar_url(:thumb), class: 'round-image-50'), current_user) %>
        </li>
    <% else %>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <%= active_link_to awesome_link 'fa fa-home fa-2x', home_path, :class => 'nav-item nav-link', title: 'Home', style: 'color: white' %>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <%= active_link_to awesome_link 'fa fa-sign-in fa-2x', login_path, :class => 'nav-item nav-link', title: 'Sign in' %>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <%= active_link_to awesome_link 'fa fa-user-plus fa-2x', new_user_registration_path, :class => 'nav-item nav-link', title: 'Register' %>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <%= active_link_to awesome_link 'fa fa-info fa-2x', about_path, :class => 'nav-item nav-link', title: 'About' %>
        </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Awesome_link generates the link tag below

```
<a href="/"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-up"></i></a>
```

CSS

```
 nav a.active {
      border-style: solid;
      border-top: thick solid #27CCC0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i wonder if you can use both active_link_to and awesome_link for the same link cause both generate the `a` element.

```
  <li class="nav-item">
          <%= active_link_to awesome_link 'fa fa-home fa-3x', home_path, :class => 'nav-item nav-link', title: 'Home', style: 'color: white' %>
        </li>
```

Replace the above with

```
  <li class="nav-item">
          <%= active_link_to '<i class="ffa fa-home fa-3x" style="color:white"></i>', home_path, :class_active => 'nav-link active', :class_inactive => 'nav-link' %>
    </li>
```

Comment: This approach doesn't work. The link is outputting the raw <i> on the navigation list.

Comment: you mean th `<i>` is urlencode? possible also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16947094/can-i-use-link-to-to-link-an-image-and-a-text

Comment: The new method works perfectly. I needed to add the <i> tag to the do block, which allows me to use the icons effortlessly without the awesome_link.